# Открыть и закрыть search input по 1 кнопке, чистый js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно выполнить проверку на чистом JS, что инпут открыт и его сразу закрывать не нужно?
Мне необходимо реализовать на 1 кнопку и открытие и закрытие search input.

Код на JS

```
const button = document.querySelector('section');
const input = document.querySelector('#inputfield');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    input.classList.add('open')
});
```

Css

```
#inputfield {
    display: none;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  }

  .search-logo {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  #inputfield.open {
    left: 62rem;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4rem;
  }

  #inputfield.remove {
    display: none;
}
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи!

Comment: Пример https://jsfiddle.net/japmwrt7/

Comment: @soledar10 благодарю)

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться методом [`.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)

```
input.classList.toggle('open')
```

либо вручную проверить наличие класса ([`.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains)) и в зависимости от результата проверки добавить/удалить ([`.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add)/[`.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove))

```
if (input.classList.contains('open')) {
    input.classList.remove('open')
} else {
    input.classList.add('open')
}
```